# Explanation of the 'JSON Template' within SXAs 'JSON Variants'

Tags: sxa, scriban, json

I am currently struggeling a bit with understanding the capabilities of the JSON Variants in SXA.

We are on SXA 9.3 and I want to make some customizations to the JSON representation with a JSON variant.

On [this page, there is a brief documentation for all the types of fields](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/introducing-sxa-data-modeling.html), you can use within a JSON Variant.

If I did not misunderstand, there should be a way with "JSON Template" to also use Scriban within a JSON Variant, however I am unable to get anything rendered here.

I tried templates with the simplest content, e.g. "test" or only curly brackets "{}" but I do not get any output.

My guess is, that the template has to follow a specific syntax or that it might only work in combination with another type of field, but I don't see that in the doc.

Has someone used Scriban templates in JSON Variants before and could give me a nudge into the right direction?

Hope I described in an understandable way :)

Cheers, Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a support request and got the response, that within JSON variants the JSON Template is only supported from version 10.2 onwards.

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Accelerator/10x/Sitecore%20Experience%20Accelerator%201020/Release%20Notes

> "You can now use Scriban templates in JSON variants. 483214"

Since we are on extended support with 9.3 now, there will not be a fix for this. They created a change request for the documentation to remove the fields now to prevent confusion.

So I was chasing a ghost after all.

Cheers, Simon